# Para serviço node de dentro do js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom estou precisando finalizar um processo de node de dentro do próprio js. O que acontece que tenho uma cron que executa um comando `node meu_arquivo.js` e preciso dentro deste `meu_arquivo.js` finalizar o node para que ele não fique aberto.

Como fazer isto ?

Comment: Nunca usei, mas existe o [tree-kill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill)

Comment: @LucasCosta achei algo próprio do node. Respondi minha pergunta la

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ligue para o método `process` do objeto global exit:

[Documentação](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)

> **process.exit ([código])**
>
> Termina o processo com o especificado code. Se omitido, exit usa o código 'sucesso' 0.
>
> Para sair com um código 'falha':
>
> process.exit(1);
>
> O shell que executou o nó deve ver o código de saída como 1.